# NSURLConnection Make a Custom Class in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

In My Project more than 6 classes having NSURLConnection's and i feel to have to create one NSURLConnection Class and reuse this class to all class But i don't know how to do this can some help me with this and give me some examples if you have thanks all in advance

```
.h
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

        @interface Connections : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
        {
            NSArray * array;
            NSMutableData * data;
        }

.m
    #import "Connections.h"

    @implementation Connections


    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
    {
        [data appendData:theData];
    }
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    }
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }
    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass "NSObject" class, write your NSURLConnections and its response handling code in it.

Use custom delegates to pass the data that you will get as a response to respective viewControllers.

OR

If you would prefer using a third party way :-

[FOLLOW THIS LINK](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

This library makes the server communication and receiving the response much more easier.

**ADDITIONS:-**
When you create a NSObject class, you should first write a method so that you can pass the parameters to initiate a connection: Like below

```
+(void)makeWebRequestWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters forService:(NSString *)service {

    requestParameters = [NSMutableString new];

    for (NSString * keys in parameters.allKeys) {
        [requestParameters appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&",keys,[parameters objectForKey:keys]]];
    }

    NSString * myString = [self removeand:requestParameters];

    NSLog(@"REQUEST PARAMETERS: %@", requestParameters);

    NSData *postData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",BASE_URL,service]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [conn start];
}
```

Then use the "NSURLConnection" delegates to handle you the data you would get in response

In any of your view controllers call the above method like :

```
[connection makeWebRequestWithParameters:parameters forService:optional];
```

Don't forget to declare "makeWebRequest..." method in ".h" file of your NSObject class

Comment: I will try it now this third party also provides the json parsing ?

Comment: It won't parse json for you .. but you have to write parsing yourself.

Comment: okay i already created the NSObject class and written the nsurlconnection delegates methods and i dont know how to use this class can you help me i just created the nsobject class and written the delegate methods of nsurlconnection and nest how i have to use this methodsin my classes

Comment: Use custom delegate to pass the data to the respective view controllers. 

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-custom-delegates--mobile-10848

Refer this link above

Comment: please check the code i added nsobject and how to use this ?

Comment: Read the tutorial I have posted in my previous comment .. to understand how you can pass the response to respective ViewControllers